# Querying for index schema (full text search) fails when not in global namespace

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

When I query for the schema of an index in full text search, in a non global namespace, I get this error: Index with incorrect namespace received "".

Here is the code I am using:

ListIndexesResponse response = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().listIndexes(
    ListIndexesRequest.newBuilder().setSchemaFetched(true).build());

// List out elements of each Schema
for (Index index : response) {
    Schema schema = index.getSchema();
    for (String fieldName : schema.getFieldNames()) {
        List typesForField = schema.getFieldTypes(fieldName);
    }
}

Event though I'm not in the global namespace, it seems to return a schema that is, which causes this error.

Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Search API does not use namespaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/overview#App_Engine_APIs_that_Use_Namespaces) by default.

There is a way to set namespaces by hand: [`SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService(namespace)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/SearchServiceFactory#getSearchService%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I get the same error.